# How can I hide the content to the users who didn't like the Facebook page?

Tags: social-network, javascript

I need to do a site where the content will be inaccessible to the visitors who have not liked the Facebook page. It is necessary to display a popup with the like button the visitor should use to like the Facebook page and see the content.

How can I do it in Drupal?

Comment: Looks like you want whole functionality written from scratch. See [help](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you have question about given step of the process, it might be a better question. On the other hand, things like [Detect Facebook page fan on the website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070465/detect-facebook-page-fan-on-the-website) are pretty easy to find already.

Comment: But what do you achieve by forcing those 'Likes'?

Comment: @AgA - of course he would achieve high like count. After all, people might refuse to like page after reading what's on it, right? Just like fast foods require you to pay before you eat ;)

Comment: @AgA - it is the client's request, not worth to discuss it with the client...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Jquery/javascript. Access the facebook like of the page, if it isn't liked then hide the page on the fly(by changing background color etc) and then prompt.

You can load any javascript file in Drupal using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in a module.

This procedure will be easiest and also will not require any time delay in showing the page.